# Topology: smooth p-manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am new to topology and getting confused about some notions.

The question is simple. Are these two statements are equivalent?:

- $M$ is a convex smooth $p$-manifold with boundary.
- $M$ is a convex and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$ whose boundary is a smooth orientable surface.

Thank you!

Examples are closed $p$-ball $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^p | \Vert x \Vert_{2} \leq 1\} $ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x_{2} \ge x_{1}^2\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by a smooth **convex** manifold with boundary?

Comment: @MoisheKohan If it is not well defined, I can just remove the qualifier. I thought a convex manifold is analogous to a convex set.

Comment: Then think of $[0,1]\sqcup [2,3]$ or the 2-dimensional annulus: Can you realize either one as a convex subset of $R^n$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Obviously, none of them are convex in their domain of respective dimension. Is this right?

Comment: Right. Does this answer your question?